# sed adds characters where it shouldn't add

Tags: terminal, sed, osx-yosemite

I have the following line (in a file called `1atp.pdb`:

```
MASTER      421    1    5   16    9    0   12    6 3070    2   66   29
```

And I'm using sed:

```
grep MASTER 1atp.pdb | sed 's/[0-9]*/xddddd/'
```

which yields:

```
xdddddMASTER      421    1    5   16    9    0   12    6 3070    2   66   29
```

There isn't any character before `MASTER`, what could be wrong?

Comment: if the suspect was a funny char in the file then you could use xxd to view the file but in this case it's not, it's just a regex thing, * matching 0 characters hence matching a position at the beginning.

Comment: Note that your `sed` string makes only a single substitution. If you want to replace all the numbers, the substitute string will need a `g` after it, viz `sed 's/[0-9]+/xddddd/g'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a regex thing.

What is happening, is `*` matches 0 characters so matches a position at the beginning. So try `+` or `{1,}`  either means 1 character or more. Also, use sed `-r` to ensure the `+` or `{1,}` is recognized.  e.g. `sed -r 's/[0-9]+/xddddd/'`  or `sed -r 's/[0-9]{1,}/xddddd/'`  or `-R` is even better if your sed has it, it supports lookahead e.g. `(?=c)` though all you need is `-r`.